# I want it to work as much as the value entered from the input

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

```
inputField.addEventListener("keyup",(e)=>{
        let inputVal=inputField.value;
        

        if(e.key==="Enter" && inputVal.length > 0){

            //for(let i=0;i<inputVal;i++){
        
                optionImages.forEach((image,index) => {
                    image.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{    
                        image.classList.add("active");
                        
                        userResult.src = cpuResult.src="images/rock.png";
                        result.textContent= "Wait..."
            
                        optionImages.forEach((image2,index2)=>{
                            if (index!=index2) {
                                image2.classList.remove("active");
                                
                            }
                        });
                        
                        gameContainer.classList.add("start");
                        
                        
                            
                    });
            });
            //}
        }
    });
```

I want the code to run as much as the value entered from the input, but when I do it with a for loop, the foreach part continues to run forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to an integer in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To run the code as many times as the value entered in the input, you can use a `for` loop. However, in your current implementation, the forEach loop inside the `keyup` event listener is being attached to the `optionImages` array multiple times, which is causing the loop to run indefinitely.

To fix this, you can move the `forEach` loop outside of the `keyup` event listener and use a separate function to handle the click event on the images. Then, inside the `keyup` event listener, you can call the function as many times as the value entered in the input.

Here's an example implementation:

```
function handleImageClick(index) {
    optionImages.forEach((image2, index2) => {
        if (index != index2) {
            image2.classList.remove("active");
        }
    });

    image.classList.add("active");
    userResult.src = cpuResult.src = "images/rock.png";
    result.textContent = "Wait...";
    gameContainer.classList.add("start");
}

inputField.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    let inputVal = inputField.value;

    if (e.key === "Enter" && inputVal.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < inputVal; i++) {
            optionImages.forEach((image, index) => {
                image.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    handleImageClick(index);
                });
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In this implementation, the `handleImageClick` function is defined outside of the keyup event listener and takes the index of the clicked image as a parameter. Inside the function, the forEach loop is used to remove the `active` class from all images except the clicked image, and then add the active class to the clicked image.

Inside the keyup event listener, the for loop is used to attach the click event listener to each image as many times as the value entered in the input. The handleImageClick function is called with the index of the clicked image as a parameter.